# Documentation on Tokens in an Element?

Tags: asp.net, html, angularjs

I am fiddling with the [AnguolarJS SPA Template for Visual Studio 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83) and am looking for documentation on tokens in an HTML5 element.
I'm using some examples to learn from and have noticed an interesting string in a class tag

```
<form class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
```

Note being able to find any info on W3.org led me to believe it's an AngularJS thing. Is this true? 
Where do i find documentation on how this works?

Comment: Those are [Bootstrap grid classes](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/), they have nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: @bmleite Thank you very much!!! how do i accept this as an answer?

Comment: Just added it as response. You should be able to accept it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) grid classes.

You can find more information [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and some examples [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).